# Read a .csv into pandas from F: drive on Windows 7

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a .csv file on my F: drive on Windows 7 64-bit that I'd like to read into pandas and manipulate.

None of the examples I see read from anything other than a simple file name (e.g. 'foo.csv').

When I try this I get error messages that aren't making the problem clear to me:

```
import pandas as pd

trainFile = "F:/Projects/Python/coursera/intro-to-data-science/kaggle/data/train.csv"
trainData = pd.read_csv(trainFile)
```

The error message says:

```
IOError: Initializing from file failed
```

I'm missing something simple here.  Can anyone see it?

Update:

I did get more information like this:

```
import csv

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trainPath = 'F:/Projects/Python/coursera/intro-to-data-science/kaggle/data/train.csv'
    trainData = []
    with open(trainPath, 'r') as trainCsv:
        trainReader = csv.reader(trainCsv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for row in trainReader:
            trainData.append(row)
    print trainData
```

I got a permission error on read.  When I checked the properties of the file, I saw that it was read-only.  I was able to read 892 lines successfully after unchecking it.

Now pandas is working as well.  No need to move the file or amend the path.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: honestly, your best bet is to move the file...but if you don't want to do that, try using `os` module to change into that directory and just call `train.csv'

Comment: have you tried providing a buffer instead of a filepath? `pd.read_csv(open(trainFile))`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I cannot promise that this will work, but it's worth a shot:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

trainFile = "F:/Projects/Python/coursera/intro-to-data-science/kaggle/data/train.csv"

pwd = os.getcwd()
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(trainFile))
trainData = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(trainFile))
os.chdir(pwd)
```

Comment: @RyanSaxe I'm pretty sure the thing you suggested is not the same as this and will, in fact, not work.

Comment: how is it not? you use `os.chdir` to change into the directory of the file and execute it...

Answer (score 5):

A better solution is to use literal strings like r'pathname\filename' rather than 'pathname\filename'. See [Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html) for more details.

Answer (score 5):

This happens to me quite often. Usually I open the csv file in Excel, and save it as an xlsx file, and it works.

so instead of

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"...\file.csv")
```

Use:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r"...\file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same issue and got that resolved .

Check your path for the file correctly

I initially had the path like

```
dfTrain = pd.read_csv("D:\\Kaggle\\labeledTrainData.tsv",header=0,delimiter="\t",quoting=3)
```

This returned an error because the path was wrong .Then I have changed the path as below.This is working fine.

```
dfTrain = dfTrain = pd.read_csv("D:\\Kaggle\\labeledTrainData.tsv\\labeledTrainData.tsv",header=0,delimiter="\t",quoting=3)
```

This is because my earlier path was not correct.Hope you get it reolved

Comment: I'm getting confused by your corrected code. It seems that you typed `dfTrain = `  and `\\labeledTrainData.tsv` twice, but if you deleted all these two, the initial path is the same as this one. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure the path is correct, make sure no other programs have the file open. I got that error once, and closing the Excel file made the error go away.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd


trainFile = os.path.join('F:',os.sep,'Projects','Python','coursera','intro-to-data-science','train.csv' )
trainData = pd.read_csv(trainFile)
```