# Reading a file using a relative path in a Python project

Tags: python, python-3.x, io, relative-path, python-import

Say I have a Python project that is structured as follows:

```
project
    /data
        test.csv
    /package
        __init__.py
        module.py
    main.py
```

`__init__.py`:

```
from .module import test
```

`module.py`:

```
import csv

with open("..data/test.csv") as f:
    test = [line for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

`main.py`:

```
import package

print(package.test)
```

When I run `main.py` I get the following error:

```
 C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\project>python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import package
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\project\package\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .module import test
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\project\package\module.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open("../data/test.csv") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data/test.csv'
```

However, if I run `module.py` from the `package` directory, I don’t get any errors. So it seems that the relative path used in `open(...)` is only relative to where the originating file is being run from (i.e `__name__ == "__main__"`)? How can deal with this, using relative paths only?

Comment: As a sidenote, quoting from PEP8: _“Relative imports for intra-package imports are highly discouraged. Always use the absolute package path for all imports.”_ Here, `from package.module import test`.

Comment: This should be a duplicate of [How do I get the path and name of the python file that is currently executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50499), as well as (as I originally closed it) [open() gives FileNotFoundError / IOError: '\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201928). The issue is the same, and it's extremely common.

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory).
If you do not want your path to be relative, it must be absolute.

But there is an often used trick to build an absolute path from current script: use its [`__file__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#__file__) special attribute:

```
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent / "../data/test.csv"
with path.open() as f:
    test = list(csv.reader(f))
```

This requires python 3.4+ (for the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module).

If you still need to support older versions, you can get the same result with:

```
import csv
import os.path

my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(my_path, "../data/test.csv")
with open(path) as f:
    test = list(csv.reader(f))
```

*[***2020 edit:*** python3.4+ should now be the norm, so I moved the pathlib version inspired by jpyams' comment first]*

Comment: Of course, if you're using Python 3.4+, you can just use [pathlib.Path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html): `Path(__file__).parent.resolve()`

Answer (score 50):

For Python 3.4+:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

base_path = Path(__file__).parent
file_path = (base_path / "../data/test.csv").resolve()

with open(file_path) as f:
    test = [line for line in csv.reader(f)]
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
with open('data/test.csv') as f:
```

Comment: This probably only works when you're running the code from the parent directory of `data/`, but not in general, so it's not likely to reliable solution.

Comment: In fact, it's not an answer to the question at all, since OP specifically asked about a solution that would work when run from anywhere rather than just from a specific folder.

Answer (score 4):

My Python version is **Python 3.5.2** and the solution proposed in the accepted answer didn't work for me. I've still were given an error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

when I was running `my_script.py` from the terminal. Although it worked fine when I run it through Run/Debug Configurations from the [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) IDE (PyCharm 2018.3.2 (Community Edition)).

**Solution**:

instead of using:

```
my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + some_rel_dir_path
```

as suggested in the accepted answer, I used:

```
my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + some_rel_dir_path
```

**Explanation**:

Changing `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`
solves the following problem:

When we run our script like that: `python3 my_script.py`
the `__file__` variable has a just a string value of "my_script.py" without path leading to that particular script. That is why method `dirname(__file__)` returns an empty string "". That is also the reason why `my_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + some_rel_dir_path` is actually the same thing as `my_path = some_rel_dir_path`. Consequently `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` is given when trying to use `open` method because there is no directory like "some_rel_dir_path".

Running script from PyCharm IDE Running/Debug Configurations worked because it runs a command `python3 /full/path/to/my_script.py` (where "/full/path/to" is specified by us in "Working directory" variable in Run/Debug Configurations) instead of just`python3 my_script.py` like it is done when we run it from the terminal.

Comment: It is indeed a caveat. It's so uncommon to run script explicitly that you seem to be the first to notice (usually you would put `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top, mark it executable and run it as `./myscript.py`). The `pathlib.Path` version does not have this gotcha though as is probably a better option since python3.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
with open(f"{os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])}/data/test.csv", newline='') as f:
```

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised when the following code worked.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("../FutureBookList"):
    if file.endswith(".adoc"):
        filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        print(filename)
        print(file_extension)
        continue
    else:
        continue
```

So, I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) and it says:

> Changed in version 3.6: Accepts a path-like object.

[path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object):

> An object representing a file system path. A path-like object is
> either a str or...

I did a [little more digging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and the following also works:

```
with open("../FutureBookList/file.txt") as file:
   data = file.read()
```

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question, which is about making such an open statement work from somewhere else than a specific directory.