# function run from a program in a different directory can no longer find its file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.6.0 and having trouble with a project across several directories. The directory structure looks like this:

```
/project
/project/frontend
```

All the functionality of my frontend is finished and tested locally and lives in `/project/frontend` and I now want to connect it with my backend which lives in `/project`

So I changed into `/project/frontend` and ran `display_page.py` which contains the lines:

```
sys.path.append('../')
from text_algorithms import process_text
```

..where `text_algorithms.py` sits in `/project` and works fine when run from there. So it started running for a good thirty seconds then crashed, complaing that it couldn't find its pickle file which sits in `/project` There is never a problem when `text_algorithms.py` is run or imported from `/project` `text_algorithms.py` contains the lines:

```
with open('english_vocab.pickle', 'rb') as f:
    v = pickle.load(f)
```

So I thought I could 'fool' it by running  `python frontend/display_page.py` from the directory below but that created a different error, namely,

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text_algorithms'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? - how to make sure that it will not change where it looks for that file depending on where you call it from. Is there a proper way to deal with this situation?

It should find its file wherever it is run from.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in the root and all its subdirectories?

Comment: I read you don't need that in Python 3.3+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139786/is-init-py-not-required-for-packages-in-python-3

Comment: If you are going to use `sys.path` hacks, then don't use relative paths: `sys.path.append('../')`. You should probably just add the root directory to your path environment variable. Perhaps inside a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that was a hack how else are you supposed to import a function from a file in another directory? Looks like I've found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-file-using-relative-path-in-python-project/40416154#40416154) read the absolute path then `os.chdir` to it but say if I'm using one hack to cancel out another.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I had to add this ridiculously long line `sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), os.pardir))` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder) in order to make that relative path thing foolproof

Comment: @cardamom yep. Which is why you should probably add the root directory to your path variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `import` other modules of your project:

```
from frontend.text_algorithms import process_text
```

If in `text_algorithms` you want to access files relative to this module then you should use the value of `__file__` which contains the file path to the particular module. With `os.path` you can obtain the directory and join it with the data file path.

For example:

```
file_path = os.path.join(
    os.path.split(__file__)[0],
    'some.file'
)
```

Comment: Thanks I also am thinking something with `os.path` and `__file__` will fix it testing it out

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. Why did it take me 49 minutes to get it to work.. I don't think your import statement with the dot is different to the `import..from` method **but** it was those 4 lines `os.path.join...` in the file of the directory below that did it. I wish you had written something like `dictionary_file =` that thing took me a while to realise those 4 lines were not changing the path but simply creating a string with the correct path to the file, wherever it is called from.