# Opening a file from an imported function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, relative-path, absolute-path

I've been "fighting" with absolute and relative paths in Python for a while and I know that there are quite a few questions on this topic, but I couldn't find an answer to my particular problem.

Given the following project structure:

```
package/
    subpackage1/
        moduleX.py
        moduleY.py
    subpackage2/
        moduleZ.py
        folder1/
            file1.txt
```

I am importing in `moduleX.py` a function from `moduleZ.py` which requires information stored in `file1.txt` to work. I have no problem importing the function from `moduleZ.py`, however since it requires `file1.txt` I get the error message "No such file or directory".

My question is: When the function from `moduleZ.py` tries to open `file1.txt` after being imported which path does it consider?

I would like for it to work with a relative path, but I couldn't find a way for it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: When the function from moduleZ.py tries to open file1.txt after being imported which path does it consider?

It considers relative paths starting from the working directory of the person/process running the code.

One of the standard ways of finding data files is to note the directory name of the root of your package, ie. in `package/__init__.py`:

```
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

then whenever you want to access a file:

```
from package import DIRNAME
file1_txt = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'subpackage2', 'folder1', 'file1.txt')
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to putting something like in the moduleZ.py to get the path you are currently in and then do the relative path from the variable you generate?

```
import os
mypath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
txtfile = os.path.join(mypath,folder1,file1.txt)
```

Comment: I was just using a relative path like `with open("folder1/file1.txt")`. I believe your solution can work, but it meant searching for the current directory in every module I want to open a file. I was looking for a more straightforward solution, if it exists.

Comment: @JoséSantos This might be a useful link for some ideas on what you are looking for.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-file-using-relative-path-in-python-project