# How to import config file when calling script from somewhere in the system?

Tags: python, cwd

lets assume i have a Folder  "myProject" with a script "mySkript.py" and a config file "myConfig.py".

When calling the script from within "myProject" i would do something like this:

```
with open("myConfig") as configurationRawData:
    # do something
```

Now lets assume i don't call the script from "myProject" folder but from "User/desktop". In this case, the open command will not actually find "myConfig". 
I am looking to make my skript use it's own path as root path and inherit this property to every other script it might call during execution.
Any ideas?

Comment: `open("myConfig")` will not open "myConfig.py". These are two different file names.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Opening a file from an imported function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994911/opening-a-file-from-an-imported-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it :

```py
import os

config_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"myConfig.py")

with open(config_file) as configurationRawData:
    # do something
```

---

`__file__` is a internal python variable that represents the path to the current file (something like `C:\Users\user\documents\scripts\mySkript.py` for windows per example). It leads to the file itself, it does not depends on working directory.

`os.path.dirname(__file__)` gives you the directory to the current file (`C:\Users\user\documents\scripts\` for the example above).

`os.path.join()` builds a path like your os likes it, so it will produce `C:\Users\user\documents\scripts\myConfig.py` for the example above.

This will work whatever your operating system is (python handles it for you) and as long as your two files are in the same directory.