# Using relative paths in Python with AWS Cloud9

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, relative-path, aws-cloud9

Using AWS Cloud9 for a Python 3.x application. I am trying to open a file (using `with open`) in the same directory as the python file, however, it only works if I define the absolute path.

---

***Relative Path***

```py
import csv

with open("test.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

*Error in Terminal*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.py", line 3, in <module>
   with open("test.csv", newline='') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test.csv'
```

---

***Absolute Path***

```py
import csv

with open("/home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

*No Errors*

Comment: your script is in here `/home/ec2-user/environment/Lab5/lab5.py` your file is in here `"/home/ec2-user/environment/test/test.csv"`, so if you want to use relative path in your code, you should call `open("../../test/test.csv", newline='')`

Comment: or simply put your file at the same folder as your script

Comment: Sorry, I changed it to a simpler path for the question. Updating question.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question, posted an answer below that works. [Reading file using relative path in python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-file-using-relative-path-in-python-project)

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(__file__).parent / "test.csv"

with path.open() as f:
    reader = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|'))
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I am gonna answer here and hope it is right for you.
AWS uses Linux OSes, if you want to use a file in Linux in the same folder the script you are running, you have to prepend `./` in the file's name, e.g. in your case:

```
import csv

with open("./test.csv", newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

Comment: That works locally, but not on AWS.