# Python Relative Path Import: Import packages from another project directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know there are many questions on this topic but none of them helped me much.

I have a python project directory i.e. `git_project` (git repository). What I want is to create a separate directory called `notebooks` where I will keep all my notebooks for analysis using git_project. I don't want to put notebooks within the root of git_project. I have kept both `git_project` and `notebooks` directory in a general directory where keep all of my projects. I have the following structure:

```
my_projects
│ 
├── notebooks
│   └── notebook.ipynb
└── git_project
    └── config
        └── cfg.json
    └── source
        └── config.py
```

The contents of `config.py`:

```
import json
def get_cfg():
     with open('config/cfg.json', 'r') as f:
         cfg = json.load(f)
     return cfg
```

Contents of the `notebook.ipynb`:

```
import sys
import os

module_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)

from git_project.source.config import get_cfg
get_cfg()
```

Now when I run the code in notebook.ipynb I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6796ee7f0100> in <module>
----> 1 get_cfg()

~/Documents/my_projects/git_project/source/config.py in get_cfg()
      1 def get_cfg():
----> 2     with open('config/cfg.json', 'r') as f:
      3         cfg = json.load(f)
      4     return cfg

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'config/cfg.json'
```

However, If I move the `notebook.ipynb` file to the root of git_project. Then I do not get this error. This is just one example. I have so many similiar problems in other modules of git_project and git_project contains the code which is already running in the production environment. So changing anything in git_project is not feasible here.
But as I said I do not want to move the notebooks inside of git_project but rather like to keep them in a parallel directory for analysis purposes. I can provide more information, if required.

I am using Python 3.6+ which does not even require to put **init**.py file anymore to make a directory package.

What should I do in order for this to work? Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `../git_project/config/cfg.json` for path in `get_cfg()`. But ideally `get_cfg(path)` would take a path variable so you could easily call it from various places without editing the function itself.

Comment: make sure your `git_project` has `__init__.py` file in the root

Comment: Even though approaches with relative paths works, often it is better to use more explicit way - something like `environment variable` with your project root, in this case, your notebooks are truly independent of the project and can be used with as many as you want. 

Just set `MY_PROJECT_ROOT` environment variable in any way you prefer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37890898/how-to-set-env-variable-in-jupyter-notebook)
and then use `getenv('MY_PROJECT_ROOT')` instead of `os.path.join('..')`

Comment: @Ahmet: But If I change the path, wouldn't it be dependent on notebook directory location?

Comment: @EugeneK: I did not understand how do you mean to use the Environment Variable from Jupyter notebook? Can you give me an example?

Comment: Yes, if you give relative path. Or give absolute pat, either way the error your getting simply means your path is wrong.

Comment: @AMIT please check my response below

Answer (score 1):

The issue was when you call `open('config/cfg.json', 'r')`, the path it opens was relative to the directory where the python code is launched.  In this case, it is your `my_projects/notebook` directory.  You can see this by adding the following prints in `get_cfg()` inside `config.py`:

```
print(os.getcwd())  # this prints out the current working directory
print(__file__)     # this prints out the path of this script
```

As Ahmet suggested, modfiying the path to `../git_project/config/cfg.json` will work, but your python implementation will be tied to the notebook folder location.  If you decide to restructure the notebook folder, it will break again.
One potential way is to parse the script path: `__file__`:

```
import json
import os
def get_cfg():
    script_dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    config_path = os.path.join(script_dirname, '..', 'config', 'cfg.json')
    with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
        cfg = json.load(f)
    return cfg
```

Similar suggestion: ([Reading file using relative path in python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-file-using-relative-path-in-python-project/40416154)).  This is also the approach that is suggested in [python-packaging docs](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/non-code-files.html):

> Files which are to be used by your installed library (e.g. data files
> to support a particular computation method) should usually be placed
> inside of the Python module directory itself. ...
> That way, code which loads those files can easily specify a relative
> path from the consuming module’s `__file__` variable.

If you don't want to touch the current file inside `git_project`, you can run a change directory command in your python notebook to point to the right location:

```
In [1]: %cd ../git_project
```

This line needs to be called once each time you restart the notebook kernel.  You can verify the current working directory in the notebook as well:

```
In [2]: %ls
```

Comment: Actually this approach works but the problem is that I can't change the code in git_project because there are many instances where such type of importation exists. Also changing the code from an analysis point of view would affect the production runs and hence will require further testing. So I am looking for a possible solution which does not force me to change much in git_project and let me use git_project as an external package / library.

Comment: In that case, would changing the directory in the notebook be ok? I just ran `%cd ../git_project` in the notebook before running your code, and the path resolves just fine. You may still need to use my original suggestion when moving git_project to a package.

Comment: By your original suggestion, do you mean changing the contents of config.py file in git_project? That would be not feasible. But your later suggestion `%cd ../git_project` works very well. I like it much better, though I don't know if it is the standard way of working in case of some one using multiple projects e.g. git_project1, git_project2 from a notebook.

Comment: It is not the standard, but I use it for a quick run.  The suggested approach is to edit the config.py file (please see the quote in the updated answer).  This also solves the problem with multiple projects since the file loading will no longer be dependent on where is your current working directory is at.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup from the discussion in the comments...

Even though approaches with relative paths work, often it is better to use a more scalable approach - environment variable with your project root.

In this case, your notebooks are truly independent of the project and can be used with as many as you want.
Here is a great [explanation](https://medium.com/@yuthakarn/how-to-not-show-credential-in-jupyter-notebook-c349f9278466) of how to use `ENV` variables in Jupiter.
I prefer to use `dotenv` approach.
Create `.env` in your notebooks folder. Add your variable with your project path:

```
MY_PROJECT_ROOT=/usr/any/path/you/want
```

Then in your notebook

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()  # this line loads .env file
```

then your code

```
module_path = os.path.abspath(os.getenv('MY_PROJECT_ROOT'))
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

Comment: Isn't it almost the same what I tried with os.path.abspath(os.path.join('..'))? But it simply adds the project directory to sys.path. But problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to change the working directory.

Initially the working directory is the notebooks directory:

```
from sys import path
import os
print("Current Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
Current Working Directory  /home/user/git_project/notebooks
```

Then you change it to the root of your project:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path[0]))
print("New Working Directory " , os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
New Working Directory  /home/user/git_project
```

After that, all imports with relative path on the project root directory should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Follow the path naming convention correctly to write your relative path"

if you want to import the Module from the Different Location Relative to your current file, you can use the following convention

yamlUtils.py is in the one folder above in the utilities/yaml/yamlUtils.py folder, make sure you have **init**.py file in all the folders having the python file.

```
import os , sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../utilities/")))
```

If you want to Read the Config Files Relatively, you can use the convention below,  .. is mean to go one level above from the location where your notebook is, and then pass the relative path. if you will follow the same folder structure, you don't have to change anything that will always work.

[image]