# Is there a way to register_shape using turtles of a random image in a file?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Attempting to make an outfit generator but need to generate a random image for the Turtle. I have files full of pictures of clothes, separated into shirts, shoes, and pants. Need the Shirts/Pants/Shoes.register_shape(random_shirt/pants/shoes) to produce a random image from said files. Not sure if this is possible but if it is please let me know.
##If there is a different easier GUI to do this with I'm open to suggestions, currently looking into TKinter.

```
import random
import turtle
import os

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.bgcolor('light gray')
wn.setup(width = 600, height = 800)
wn.title('Outfit Generator')

#Turtle of Shirt
Shirt = turtle.Turtle()
Shirt.hideturtle()
Shirt.speed(0)
Shirt.setposition(300, 400)


#Turtle of Pants
Pants = turtle.Turtle()
Pants.hideturtle()
Pants.speed(0)
Pants.setposition(500, 400)


#Turtle of Shoes
Shoes = turtle.Turtle()
Shoes.hideturtle()
Shoes.speed(0)
Shoes.setposition(100, 400)


# Specify the directory where your photos are located
photo_shirts_dir = r'C:\Users\Rest Of Path\Shirts'
photo_pants_dir = r'C:\Users\Rest Of Path\Pants'
photo_shoes_dir = r'C:\Users\Rest Of Path\Shoes'

#Create Directory of all images in files
image_files_shirts = [file for file in os.listdir(photo_shirts_dir) if file.endswith(('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]
image_files_pants = [file for file in os.listdir(photo_pants_dir) if file.endswith(('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]
image_files_shoes = [file for file in os.listdir(photo_shoes_dir) if file.endswith(('.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png'))]

if not image_files_shirts:
    print("No image files found in the directory.")
else:
    random_shirt = (random.choice(image_files_shirts))
    turtle.register_shape(random_shirt)
    Shirt.shape(random_shirt)

if not image_files_pants:
    print("No image files found in the directory.")
else:
    random_pants = random.choice(image_files_pants)
    turtle.register_shape(random_pants)
    Pants.shape(random_pants)

if not image_files_shoes:
    print("No image files found in the directory.")
else:
    random_shoes = random.choice(image_files_shoes)
    turtle.register_shape(random_shoes)
    Shoes.shape(random_shoes)


wn.listen()
wn.mainloop()
```

Error Being Received

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\joezi\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Outfit Creator\OutfitGenerator.py", line 45, in <module>
    turtle.register_shape(random_shirt)
  File "<string>", line 8, in register_shape
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\turtle.py", line 1134, in register_shape    
    shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\turtle.py", line 479, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4145, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 4092, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "shirt.gif": no such file or directory
```

Comment: Is there a problem with your current code? Looks fine to me, other than the fact that turtle [only works with gifs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.register_shape). I also suggest using `os.path.join()` rather than hardcoding backslashes.

Comment: @ggorlen It doesn't seem to work. I get hit with a ' couldn't open "shirt.gif": no such file or directory' error. But the code is obviously pulling from the file to find the gif.

Comment: Which line? Please [edit] your post to show the full stack trace.

Comment: @ggorlen Edited. Not sure why it's giving line numbers that large.

Comment: Thanks. Those are line numbers inside the Python turtle and tkinter libraries. You generally only need to look at the line in your code, `turtle.register_shape(random_shirt)`. The problem seems pretty clear from the error: you're missing the full path to the file. I'll add an answer.

Comment: @ggorlen That's what I assumed. Was just turned around because 'shirt.gif' is in a file and so obvioulsy the code had to dig to find it, was just confused how it could find it then give me the error that it couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, `os.listdir` returns a list of file names. The error `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "shirt.gif": no such file or directory` indicates that turtle is trying to open `shirt.gif` in the current working directory, which isn't right. Try prepending the path back onto the file names:

```py
random_shirt = random.choice(image_files_shirts)
shape = os.path.join(photo_shirts_dir, random_shirt)
turtle.register_shape(shape)
Shirt.shape(shape)
```

Note I'm using `os.path.join()` for an operating-system agnostic path join. This requires adding `import os` to the top of your script. I suggest using `os.path.join` for your other paths as well.

Note that your `endswith` isn't valid since turtle only works with `.gif`s at the present time. `os.path.splitext("...")[1]` is preferable to `endswith` in any case. The general rule is not to use plain string manipulation on paths to avoid bugs and gotchas.

I'd also use a relative path rather than presuming `C:\Users\...` is a thing, which it won't be on most computers.

Another nitpick: the Python convention is that `PascalCase` is only used for class names. Variables are `snake_case`.

---

When attacking problems, it's always good to minimize the problem so the situation is free of any noise, and you can focus fully on the issue.

Directory structure:

```
├── images
│   └── test.gif
└── test.py
```

test.py:

```py
import os
from turtle import Screen, Turtle


path = "images"
files = [
    x for x in os.listdir(path) if
    os.path.splitext(x)[1] == ".gif"
]

if files:
    t = Turtle()
    shape = files[0]
    Screen().register_shape(shape)
    t.shape(shape)
    Screen().exitonclick()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/programming/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    Screen().register_shape(files[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 1133, in register_shape
    shape = Shape("image", self._image(name))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/turtle.py", line 478, in _image
    return TK.PhotoImage(file=filename, master=self.cv)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4103, in __init__
    Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 4048, in __init__
    self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "test.gif": no such file or directory
```

Now, the fix:

```py
# ...
if files:
    t = Turtle()
    shape = files[0]
    Screen().register_shape(shape)
    t.shape(shape)
    Screen().exitonclick()
```

Related: [Reading a file using a relative path in a Python project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416072/reading-a-file-using-a-relative-path-in-a-python-project)

Answer (score 0):

In theory, we could use a generic name like `'shirt'` to represent a random image instead of a file path:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Shape
# ...
shape = Shape('image', full_path_name)
screen.register_shape('shirt', shape)
shirt.shape('shirt')
```

But unfortunately, this is broken by an apparent bug in turtle's `Shape.__init__` method where it invokes `_image` as a *class* method, instead of an *instance* method, effectively leaving off a `self` argument:

```
elif type_ == "image":
    if isinstance(data, str):
        if data.lower().endswith(".gif") and isfile(data):
            data = TurtleScreen._image(data)
```

where the last line probably should be something like:

```
data = Screen()._image(data)
```

Ignoring that glitch, my handling of the file path issue would be something like:

```
from random import choice
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
import os

# Specify the directory where your photos are located
PHOTO_SHIRTS_DIRECTORY = r'C:\Users\Rest Of Path\Shirts'

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('light gray')
screen.setup(width=600, height=800)
screen.title('Outfit Generator')

# Turtle of Shirt
shirt = Turtle()
shirt.penup()
shirt.speed('fastest')
shirt.setposition(300, 400)

image_files_shirts = []

# Create list of matching images in directory
with os.scandir(PHOTO_SHIRTS_DIRECTORY) as directory:
    for entry in directory:
        if entry.is_file() and os.path.splitext(entry.name)[-1].lower() == '.gif':
            image_files_shirts.append(entry.path)

if image_files_shirts:
    random_shirt = choice(image_files_shirts)
    screen.register_shape(random_shirt)
    shirt.shape(random_shirt)
else:
    print("No image files found in the shirt directory.")

screen.mainloop()
```