# Using pandas, how do I save an exported csv file to a folder relative to the scripts position?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Preferably without the entire directory address. Can I define the folder relative to my executable script's position?

```
dataframe.to_csv('findorb_data.txt',header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I think this is basically a repeat of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384358/how-to-open-my-files-in-data-folder-with-pandas-using-relative-path)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open my files in \`data\_folder\` with pandas using relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384358/how-to-open-my-files-in-data-folder-with-pandas-using-relative-path)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `__file__` variable that contains the full path to the script. So, something like this:

```
import os
file_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
csv_folder = 'csv files'
file_path = os.path.join(file_dir, csv_folder, 'findorb_data.txt')
dataframe.to_csv(file_path, header=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always use relative path syntax but you can also use something like this to find the parent directory of your script.

```
import os
import sys
script_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]) or '.')
```

So if your csv is in the folder `../csv_dir/csv.csv' you can use

```
csv_path = os.path.join(script_dir, '../csv_dir/csv.csv')
```