# Opening a csv file with pandas with relative path from another main file in another path

Tags: python, pandas, csv, relative-path

My question is similar to the one in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384358/how-to-open-my-files-in-data-folder-with-pandas-using-relative-path) but with a slight difference

the project structure is

```
project_folder
--> main.py
--> scripts_folder
    --> script.py
--> data_folder
    --> data.csv
```

The main.py looks like this

```
from scripts_folder.script import a

a()
```

The script.py looks like this

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('../data_folder/data.csv')

# do some things with df


def a():
    print('something')
```

I am running `main.py`, which calls `script.py`, which has to import data from `data.csv`.
I tried the method given in the question above. ie I tried importing using this line of code in `scripty.py` `pd.reac_csv('../data_folder/data.csv')` but it is not working.

It is giving me error

```
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data_folder/data.csv'
```

[EDIT]

I tried moving the `data.csv` into `scripts_folder` as in

```
project_folder
--> main.py
--> scripts_folder
    --> script.py
    --> data.csv
--> data_folder (empty)
```

and I changed it to `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')` and still I am getting the same error

```
    handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: if you try using 
`import os 
print(os.getcwd())` wich is the output? Maybe the directory where you are executing is not the scripts_folder

Comment: Try "data_folder/data.csv"

Comment: @Gam I tried it on all the files in my project and I got the same directory. I tried using a relative path accordingly in pandas but it still gave error.

Comment: @Echo somehow that is working for the above case but for my real project, it is giving me the same error. I have no idea why.

Comment: The issue is with the relative path. From script.py try to print the current directory as mentioned by @Gam . You will get to know what the current path is and then give your path accordingly.

Comment: @johnwick wich directory is? As mentioned by @Echo the relative path must be given to accordingly to the current working directory. Maybe the interpreter starts with a completly differen working directory. Try open a terminal and execute:
`cd "path_to_scripts_folder"` and then `python script.py`. Does this works (leaving your modifications as they are)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 handle = open(
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../data_folder/data.csv'
```

This indicates that it supposed to work inside `scripts_folder`.
`../data_folder` means get the directory up relative to the current and find `data_folder` in this directory.

You could construct absolute file path for `csv-file` using `os.path.abspath` and `os.path.join` and give it to script reading data.
To debug current working directory for script, use `os.getcwd()`